# Should I create a surrogate key?

Tags: sql, database

I'm working from a dataset where materials are tested for various descriptors. Sometimes there will be multiple values for a single material-descriptor combination. (e.g. *SKU* **ABC-001** had **flammability** *tests* done with *results* **WUXH005** and **WUXH008**)

As-is, all natural primary key candidates include the results, which seems unreasonable. It is guaranteed that a material-descriptor-result is unique. Should I add an integer surrogate key, or maybe a more meaningful surrogate like below?

```
{SKU}-{test shorthand}#{SKU-test index}
```

e.g.

```
ABC-001-Flam#1 
ABC-001-Flam#2
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use more than one table?

```
Material -- contains all the info about the material
m_id -- The material id, primary key
...

Tests
t_id -- The test id, primary key
m_id -- Foreign key to the material table
... -- descriptions et whatnot

Results
r_id -- the specific result id, primary key
t_id -- Foreign key to the test table
... -- descriptions et whatnot
```

---

To select the data, use a couple of joins:

```
select m.*, r.*
from materials m
inner join tests t
on t.m_id = m.m_id
inner join results r
on r.t_id = t.t_id
```

Comment: That had crossed my mind. It just seems like it would add complexity and more joins without really reducing the size of the database by much. When I checked SO for opinions on tables without PKs, they seemed to be very-much against the idea because Update and Delete, but for those operations I could internally use the test results.